# Can I use a protocol with a specified associated type?

Tags: swift3

The following code works:

```swift
protocol GenericStorage {
    associatedtype Value
    func store(value: Value)
}

protocol DataStorage {
    func store(value: Data)
}

struct StringStorage: GenericStorage {
    typealias Value = String

    let wrapped: DataStorage

    func convert(_ str: String) -> Data {
        return Data(str.utf8)
    }

    func store(value: String) {
        wrapped.store(value: convert(value))
    }
}
```

Can I use the `GenericStorage` protocol with an associated type of `Data` for the `wrapped` argument in `StringStorage` in order to avoid the redundant `DataStorage` protocol altogether?

I expect something like the following code (not working):

```swift
protocol GenericStorage {
    associatedtype Value
    func store(value: Value)
}

struct StringStorage: GenericStorage {
    typealias Value = String

    let wrapped: GenericStorage where Value = Data

    func convert(_ str: String) -> Data {
        return Data(str.utf8)
    }

    func store(value: String) {
        wrapped.store(value: convert(value))
    }
}
```

Comment: Without more context it is hard to give you an exact solution, since it's hard to tell what exactly do you want `wrapped.store(value: convert(value))` to do. However, your code compiles perfectly fine if you delete the typealias, the `wrapped` declaration and just define `store` as `func store(value: String) {
        convert(value)
    }`. But as from your question it isn't really clear what `store` is supposed to do in `StringStorage`, I cannot tell if this is what you actually want.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I want to have a wrapper that is of type `GenericStorage` which calls method on another `GenericStorage` although the actual associated type for `Value` might be different. I'm interested in language specifics.

Comment: for that to work in general, you would need to provide a default implementation of the `store` function (which could be a generic function), otherwise how could the compiler infer what do you mean by calling the function on a type for which you didn't specify conformance to `GenericStorage` before.

Comment: @DávidPásztor my question is, if there is a way to specify the type. Then the compiler would know it. I sketched that by adding `where Value = Data` but that is just pseudo code. With generics I could just set `struct StringStorage<T>` and then `let wrapped: GenericStorage<T>` and I wanted to know if there is a way to achieve that with protocols.

Comment: At the moment, you cannot make a protocol generic. You can only add type constraints to the associatedType (introduced in Swift4) or to the functions of the protocol.

Comment: @DávidPásztor if you turn that into an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, you would need to turn `GenericStorage` into a generic protocol. However, at the moment, you cannot make a protocol generic. You can only add type constraints to the associatedType (introduced in Swift4) or to the functions of the protocol.

For more information on generic protocols, see the [Generics Manifesto](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md).